# VS Code is not working on i'Mac Showing 'crashed', code: '11' error

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, crash

VS Code is not working on i'Mac

show this error :-

[image]

When i open the vs code in my Machine it will crashed and show me this error.

how can i fixed that please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You should uninstall VSCode and then redownload and reinstall a fresh copy of the software.